# Best method of loading data from one database to another

Tags: oracle

I have two Oracle databases. They have exactly the same table structure. There are about 15 tables that have various FK relationships.

I need to create a process that can accept an ID (The PK of the parent table for the whole database) and transfer all data in the database related to that key to the second database.

I thought about using Database links. However, it looks like this option is not "sanctioned".

What other good options are there to do this? I know there is the import/export tool for MSSql Server but I'm on Oracle. I could create a client application that would handle connecting to both databases but that seems like a lot of work for the client app. I could export to files and then import but once again that's a lot of work.

Any ideas of a good way to do this or am I pretty much stick with the solutions I already thought of?

I know this might be a tough questions to really have a solid answer, I thank everyone in advance for their help!

Answer (score 1):

There are two complementary command line tools called exp and imp for oracle. You can find some more info on them here http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ

The main bit you might be interested in is the where clause option

```
exp scott/tiger tables=emp query="where deptno=10"
```

Comment: That looks interesting. I'll take a look. Looks like there is a newer version of the commands: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Data_Pump

Comment: One questions though, How do I go about using these commands? I'm on windows xp with SQL Developer installed. Do I need to install something else?

Comment: Additionally, It looks like using this process requires a database link so to the import and export. `With network mode imports, one doesn't need any intermediate dump files (GREAT, no more FTP'ing of dump files). Data is exported across a database link and imported directly into the target database` Is this a command I can execute on my local computer, have it store the dmp file there and then load the dump file from there so I don't have to use a database link?

Comment: You need to install the standard Oracle Client software to get these utilities on your local machine.  They are probably already on your database server, in case you have access to log into it remotely.  The old `exp` command will create its dump files locally to the client, which sounds like what you need.  The newer `expdp` command will create files locally to the database server, which then means you might need to transfer them to the other server before importing.  The newer versions can also be used in network mode which does require a database link.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes I think I want to dump the files locally and then import them from the local machine. Oracle's documentation just insisted that the newer version be used. Is this load process smart enough to recognize that the order of the inserts are important because of FK relationships?

Comment: @kralco imp won't be able to make new primary keys and link the foreign keys to them.  On a normal imp, the structure is created, so order isn't an issue either, because constraints are created later. When tables exist, many things should be taken into consideration: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96652/ch02.htm#1005081

Comment: the tables will exist on the target database. This is a process I need to be able to run on a somewhat regular, but on-demand, basis. The target tables are already created with the same keys as the source table.

Comment: Is there anything to stop you doing a full backup and restore to the target database ?

Comment: yes. We were not allotted the amount of disk space necessary on the target database to move all of the data from the source to the target. We are required to move only the necessary data that related to the specific ID in question, and all the data related to that ID in the child tables.

Answer (score 1):

@kralco626 - I know this question is old, yet what you could do is create a temp table in the source database  that matches the parameters of the original table.  Then copy the records you want to move to new database from the original table to the new temp table.
syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE source_new_table
AS (SELECT * FROM source_old_table
    WHERE old_table.column_name = criteria);
```

Now export the new temp table with datapump export table command.
syntax:

```
EXPDP source_schema_name/source_schema_password TABLES=source_new_table DIRECTORY=datapump_dir DUMPFILE=dumpfile_name.dpdmp LOGFILE=expdp_logfile_name COMPRESSION=ALL
```

Take that datapump export file and use it to do an datapump import table command to the destination database.
syntax:

```
IMPDP destination_schema_name/destination_schema_password TABLES=source_new_table DIRECTORY=datapump_dir DUMPFILE=dumpfile_name.dpdmp LOGFILE=impdp_logfile_name
```

Then append the records from that newly imported temp table to the original table in the destination database.
syntax:

```
INSERT INTO destination_old_table
SELECT * FROM source_new_table;
```

Do this same step for each table that you need to grab data from in the source database.
After you're all done then you just need to delete the temp tables from both databases.
syntax:

```
DROP TABLE destination_schema_name.source_new_table;
DROP TABLE source_schema_name.source_new_table;
```

That should get you the results you want.